Specify how LocalDateTime is stored in Azure CosmosDB for NoSQL
I have a spring boot project using azure cosmos db for nosql as the database, using CosmosRepository from spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos artifact. My entity looks like this:
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.Container;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.GeneratedValue;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Container
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    private String author;
    private String content;
    private String imageUrl;
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;
}

problem is, when persisting data, creationTime is for some reason stored as an array  (example: "creationTime": [2024, 6, 16, 16, 51, 25, 571970017]), instead of an ISO string which I'd expect to be the default. This seemingly presents issues when using a repository method to sort posts by time (public List<Post> findAllByOrderByCreationTimeDesc();). Is there a way to specify that LocalDateTime be stored as an ISO string without changing creationTime to String and doing so manually? I have tried annotating creationTime with spring's @DateTimeFormat, seemingly to no avail.

Where do you see the numerical array? In the Cosmos DB, or with a debugger/inspector? Have you tried fetching this data back from Cosmos, and printing it's value? It would appear there is a serialisation issue in the framework, but just wanted to check you're not just seeing this in an inspector?

@ArchitectJamie It is a numerical array within the Cosmos DB itself when querying for container items

Interesting. Are you able to post the code you're using to write your object to Cosmos? In most cases, Java will implicitly call toString() for a LocalDateTime, producing an ISO 8601 string, but it would appear that the serialiser isn't doing thus.

@ArchitectJamie I am using CosmosRepository and its save() method, no custom code

I checked the SDK source and saw Jackson was being used for serializing to JSON. I posted an answer for you. Hopefully, this does the trick. Let me know if it needs refinement.

Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB uses Jackson under the hood for serializing objects in Json format. It's Jackson's default behaviour which is resulting in dates being persisted as numerical arrays.
Jackson does support a number of different annotations that let's it know how it should serialize input and format outout.
Option 1 - Use an Annotation
You can use the @JsonFormat annotation in your model class, specifying the recommended ISO 8601 format for Azure Cosmos DB.
@Data
@Container
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    private String author;
    private String content;
    private String imageUrl;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;
}

Option 2 - Override Default Behaviour in Application Properties
If you prefer to override Jackson's default behaviour at application scope then you can do this in your application.properties or application.yml file.
# Serialize dates as ISO 8601 strings
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'


Option one works, thanks. Not sure about the second one as serializing dates as strings already seems to be the default for spring (when inspecting REST requests), I would imagine azure package has separate config for jackson somewhere

@Overdrowsed You're most likely right. Why they would do this when it means you can't use Cosmos' built-in date functions is a mystery.

@Overdrowsed I dug a bit deeper and there are specific provisions to format ZonedDateTime objects properly, just not LocalDateTime. I guess you could use zoned instead, since the zoning information is stripped on format, but it seems like a bit of an oversight of the dev(s).

For now @JsonFormat works well enough, I may replace with ZonedDateTime or maybe make an issue on github in the future, thanks for your help
